# Collapsing navbar moves uncollapsable items away from navbar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, navbar

I have this navbar:

[image]

Where the *army of shopping carts* should not be collapsed if the screen is made smaller:

[image]

So far, so good...

However, when I click the toggle button, my *army of shopping carts* is also moved down with the menu, like this:

[image]

But I want my *army of shopping carts*, to stay up as well, like in this image (painted for now):

[image]

I've looked for a few hours now, and still can't achieve this behaviour. Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ecg65fjm/).

**Code**:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">English Park Cuisine</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="index.php">Acasa<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                Meniu
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="meniu.php">Pizza</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Paste</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Supe</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Ciorbe</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Desert</a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Contact</a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                    <p class="dropdown-item">0746117702</p>
                    <p class="dropdown-item">0742112452</p>
                    <p class="dropdown-item">0735212352</p>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="d-flex order-lg-1 ml-auto pr-2">
        <a href="#" class="navbar-text"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart fa-lg" style="color: white;"></i></a>
        <a href="#" class="navbar-text"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart fa-lg" style="color: white;"></i></a>
        <a href="#" class="navbar-text"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart fa-lg" style="color: white;"></i></a>           
    </div>

</nav>
```

The question is very similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49600559/prevent-items-from-being-collapsed-in-bootstrap-4-navbar-toggle), however, you don't see this behaviour there because the order of the navbar is different, which is what makes this question unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can approach this using [order-* classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/#order). Just keep the order `value` of the items you want to keep on the top navbar lower than the value of the `button` that toggle the collapsed mode. In the next example:

**(1)** When navbar is not collapsed (`lg` screens) the army of shopping carts will have `order-4` and go last.

**(2)** When navbar is collapsed, the army of shopping carts will have `order-1` and the toggle collapsing button will have `order-2`. So the collapse button will not affect it.

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-B4dIYHKNBt8Bc12p+WXckhzcICo0wtJAoU8YZTY5qE0Id1GSseTk6S+L3BlXeVIU" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">

  <a class="navbar-brand order-0" href="#">English Park Cuisine</a>

  <div class="order-lg-4 order-1 ml-auto mr-2">
    <a href="#" class="navbar-text">
      <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart fa-lg" style="color: white;"></i>
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="navbar-text">
      <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart fa-lg" style="color: white;"></i>
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="navbar-text">
      <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart fa-lg" style="color: white;"></i>
    </a>
  </div>

  <button class="navbar-toggler order-2" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse order-3" id="navbarNavDropdown">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="index.php">
          Acasa<span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Meniu
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="meniu.php">Pizza</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Paste</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Supe</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Ciorbe</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Desert</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Contact</a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
          <p class="dropdown-item">0746117702</p>
          <p class="dropdown-item">0742112452</p>
          <p class="dropdown-item">0735212352</p>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The link to the order classes finally pointed me in the right direction to some deeper understanding of why this was happening. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">English Park Cuisine</a>

    <div class="d-flex order-lg-1 ml-auto pr-2" style="margin-right:20px;">
        <a href="#" class="navbar-text"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart fa-lg" style="color: white;"></i></a>
        <a href="#" class="navbar-text"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart fa-lg" style="color: white;"></i></a>
        <a href="#" class="navbar-text"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart fa-lg" style="color: white;"></i></a>

    </div> 
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="index.php">Acasa<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                Meniu
            </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="meniu.php">Pizza</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Paste</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Supe</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Ciorbe</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Desert</a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Contact</a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                    <p class="dropdown-item">0746117702</p>
                    <p class="dropdown-item">0742112452</p>
                    <p class="dropdown-item">0735212352</p>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>



</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer too, however, the other one is a bit more clear and explanatory so I marked that one as accepted. But thanks for your effort, and I noted that it worked perfectly as well :)